# Cassandra node is taking hours to join

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My cluster of size 2 had entered into somewhat inconsistent state. On one node (call it node A) nodetool status was correctly showing 2 nodes. While on another node (call it B) it was showing only one i.e. itself. After several attempts I could not fixed the issue. So I decommissioned node B. But nodetool status on node A was still showing the node B that to in UN state. I had to restart cassandra on node A so that it forget node B.

But this has lead to another problem. I am making new node (call it C) to join the cluster of node A. But that node is taking hours. It's already six hours and I am wondering whether it will successfully join finally.

Looking at debug logs of node C suggest that node B (the decommissioned one) is causing trouble. Logs at node C are constantly showing:

```
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2017-04-29 12:38:40,004 Gossiper.java:337 - Convicting /10.120.8.53 with status removed - alive false
```

Nodetool status on node A is showing the node C in joining state as expected.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UJ  10.120.8.113  1006.97 MiB  256          ?       f357d8d0-2379-43d8-8ae5-62224191fb6c  rack1
UN  10.120.8.23   5.29 GiB   256          ?       596260a0-785a-435c-a3f3-632f56c5c882  rack1
```

Load for node C increases in fraction after couple of hours.

I checked whether system.peers contains node B. But the table contains zero rows.

I am using cassandra 3.7.

What's going wrong. What can I do to avoid losing data on node A and still scale the cluster?

Comment: What is RF of your cluster and CPU levels on both servers.

Answer (score 4):

Run **nodetool netstats** on node C and see if there's is a progress going on.
Also review **nodetool compactionstats**, see amount of compactions pending, and see if it goes down with time.

If the bootstraping failed, try restarting the node.

As an alternative, you can remove node C and add it once again, with **auto_bootstrap** setting set to false. After the node is up, run nodetool rebuild, and nodetool repair after the process - should be a faster alternative for regular bootstrap.

Comment: I have to opt for auto_bootstrap setting set to false. But now it seems rebuild has stuck. The logs shows the node B is still troubling. It keeps on showing log entry - "DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2017-05-01 14:12:40,371 Gossiper.java:337 - Convicting /10.120.8.53 with status LEFT - alive false"

Comment: Restart node B. When the cluster is stable run repair.

Comment: You spelled compactionstats wrongly. Can you fix that?